# Ubuntu - Black screen after installing 460 driver

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics

I have tried to install the nVidia driver version 460 many times. Every time I get a black screen with no output. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> does not bring the console terminal, and no online solutions work.
I am able to restore the system to a bootable state by using my Timeshift backup from a Live CD.
I need a newer driver version for several programs. I am able to successfully install driver version 390 though. I am using the "Additional Drivers" application on ubuntu.

***Other info :***

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Graphics Card: nVidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
- Motherboard: ASUS PRIME B560M-K

Comment: Did you try instructions on https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/black-screen-after-install-of-nvidia-driver-ubuntu/109312/5

Comment: @Jakke I have but it didnt help

Comment: Have you tried installing the drivers that come with Ubuntu?  `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: @Terrance isn't that the same as using their GUI? nVidia says driver 460 is supported for this card

Comment: Tried the autoinstall, got an error: 
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-460 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-460 (= 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Try turning on the `restricted` repo then rerun the command.  `sudo apt-add-repository restricted`

Comment: @Terrance - the `restricted` repository was already enabled on my system.

Comment: Honestly, I don't use the `autoinstall` feature here.  Seems to be the consensus of users here to use it.  I have used either the `graphics-drivers` PPA or I have just ran `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460` from a command line to install the driver.  It wasn't until recently that they added in the NVIDIA 460 driver to the Ubuntu default repositories.  The drivers that come in the Ubuntu repositories have been tested and they install the DKMS drivers that survive kernel upgrades.  Try running the `sudo apt update` and try just the regular install `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460`

Comment: Also, make sure that you have Secure Boot disabled in your BIOS or the driver will not load as it is not an official signed driver.

Comment: @Terrance I have tried disabling the secure boot thing some time ago, and the only thing I could do on this ASUS motherboard (because secure boot had no disable button) was to clear the PK which set it's state to Setup instead of User but I really dont know if its finally disabled or not.

Comment: also, I have tried the graphics-drivers PPA and the default nvidia-driver-460, both resulting in black screen after boot.

Comment: You stated other online solutions in your question, but you didn't state what you have tried.  Can you please edit your question and add in those details of what you have tried so that we are not guessing or giving you possible answers that you have already tried.  I mean, have you tried adding the `nomodeset` to your kernel line in grub that is another possible solution to fix this?  Have you tried setting the monitor frequencies in the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`?  Are you using Wayland instead of X.Org?  NVIDIA drivers do not work with Wayland.

Comment: Tried nomodeset, which gave me a "Loading initial ramdisk..." and then was stuck (CTRL+ALT+F4/3/2/1 did not help). Tried nvidia-xconfig, didnt help. Wayland is disabled.

Comment: Although I can boot perfectly fine from a Pop!_OS Live USB and have the nVidia driver load properly. So I might just switch to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Pop!_OS (a ubuntu fork) which had an nvidia iso that worked perfectly